# Vertically center text in a grid layout with grid and items 100% height

Tags: html, css

[Here's an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div) about exactly this, and I've found several others. Many of them have a dozen answers, using many (many!) combinations of align and justify styles, transforms, margins, references to table cells, etc.

I've tried maybe 200 combinations of ideas from references. Is it possible to center the text vertically?  Is it possible to do it while maintaining 100% height without adding divs around or inside the boxes?

My main finding after all this is that `height: 100%` thwarts every other style that can succeed.  For example, `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` set to `auto` works, but not with 100% height.

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
}

#boxes {
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 10em;
  min-width: 12em;
}

#boxes>div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="boxes">
    <div id="00">I'm not</div>
    <div id="01">vertically</div>
    <div id="02">centered.</div>
    <div id="10">I</div>
    <div id="11">am not</div>
    <div id="12">either!</div>
    <div id="20">Was CSS designed</div>
    <div id="21">by a psychopath?</div>
    <div id="22">Seems like it!</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I am astonished at how non-simple this simple-seeming thing is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put flex on the boxes, just like in [an answer on the post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58638216/1264804).

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox

```css
section {
  height: 400px;
}

#boxes {
  background-color: green;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 6px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 10em;
  min-width: 12em;
}

#boxes>div {
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="boxes">
    <div id="00">I'm not</div>
    <div id="01">vertically</div>
    <div id="02">centered.</div>
    <div id="10">I</div>
    <div id="11">am not</div>
    <div id="12">either!</div>
    <div id="20">Was CSS designed</div>
    <div id="21">by a psychopath?</div>
    <div id="22">Seems like it!</div>
  </div>
</section>
```